# xcode Firebase Crashlytics Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, crashlytics, xcode12, firebase-crash-reporting, xcode12.5

I have an application that I wrote with swift. I want to see crash reports of the app after the release. I want to add Firebase Crashlytics for this. I do everything in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios). but during compilation i get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/durak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelimeci-auysdliostxzkgcllzdsmxabridn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelimeci.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelimeci.build/Script-65F1AA5C273CEB5C00F5B530.sh: /bin/shr: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I've been searching for hours and can't find a solution. I removed the pod and reinstalled it, still didn't work. What is the problem, where am I going wrong?

xcode 12.5

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not understand how it happened, even though I added a new one many times, it made "/bin/shr". It was fixed when I did /bin/sh

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
In my situation because I use nvm and node version 16.13.1 when I change the version to 16.6.0 it fixes the problem.
nvm alias default 16.6.0